# How to change the position of text in seaborn jointplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I get a jointplot as following using `sns.jointplot` with `kind="kde"`.

[image: figure]

and I want to move the text to the left corner, what should I do here? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may change the `loc`ation of the legend via the `_set_loc()` method. Possible locations are numbers from 0 to 10, which denote the edges of the axes.

```
g = sns.jointplot(...)
g.ax_joint.get_legend()._set_loc(4)
```

E.g. `loc=4` is the lower right corner. The upper left corner would be `loc=2`

[image: loc parameter]
[Image taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43439132/4124317)]